# error while passing const pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, reference, constants

I am trying to correct a piece of C++ code. (it was written for this purpose and so were the errors...)

> error: invalid conversion from `'const Book*'` to `std::vector<Book*>::value_type {aka Book*}'` [-fpermissive]

in this method

```
void Bibliography::addBook(const Book *newBook)
{
    books.push_back(newBook);
}
```

the vector is defined as

```
std::vector<Book *> books;
```

Now my main question is, how far does const reach? does it mean "this function can't modify newBook" or does it make the element in the vector a const too?

Based on that answer, do i have to remove the const, or is there another way to fix this?

Comment: If i understand const correctly that would mean that the book itself is const? in that case no, the book is editable

Comment: yes, this works, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

> *From the comments:*
>
> Would `std::vector<const Book *> books;` be OK?
>
> > no, the book is editable

If the `book` a pointer to which you are pushing into the vector is to remain mutable, then `const` qualifier needs to be removed from the parameter type of `addBook`. Otherwise, the `book` object passed by pointer must be treated as `const`.

> is there another way to fix this?

I would recommend using a vector of shared or unique *smart* pointers in place of a vector of regular pointers. This would help you manage memory automatically:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Book>> books;
```

[Unique pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) will free the memory when the `Book` object is removed from the vector.

Comment: does this work if i add the book to multiple vectors? or should i use shared pointers in that case?

Comment: @Wouter Correct, if you are adding objects to different containers, you need to use `std::shared_ptr<T>` instead.

Comment: however if i use the `const Book` as vector element, can i still change the original object to update the vector? i'm kinda confused about this now. (i want to change it directly, not going through the vector)

Comment: @Wouter If you store `const` pointer in the vector, you could still use the original, non-`const`, pointer to modify the object. It is only if you go through the vector that would prevent you from modifying the `Book` or call any of its non-`const` member functions.